# AngularFire Database - how to get count of a list

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I tried to use angularfire2 to create a method to return the count of a list in a firebase real-time database. for example:

Get count of users in '/users'. I don't need to 'observe' or 'watch' the change of this number. Just get the count of the users. So the signature of the method would be:

```
getUserCount(): number { ... }
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any way to get the count of children using AngularFire2 (without loading all items of the list). You can use [REST API with shallow parameter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#shallow):

```
this.http.get('https://your-app-name.firebaseio.com/users.json?shallow=true')
  .map(response => response.json())
  .subscribe(items => Object.keys(items).length)
```

Another way to achieve this is to build a *trigger* updating a counter in your Firebase realtime database when you add or remove a user and querying it to get the count of users.